# How to use markdown for maven project site?

Tags: maven, markdown, maven-site-plugin

How to start with project documentation using maven and markdown markup language?
Maven site default is APT, which is uncomfortable to learn just to do thing maven way.
(Usually nobody in a team will start writing maven site documentation when they also need to learn one more markup language along the way.)

Has anybody tried to use markdown (the same markup language as used on github) for Maven project site documentation? I see from [Maven Doxia references](http://maven.apache.org/doxia/references/index.html) that it is possible.
Any issues?

I am new to maven site generation. I think markdown is better to start with, than others markup languages, that the team has not worked with.

UPDATE. Succeeded. See answer below.

Comment: Not yet. I have planned to do that before end of February. I will post my own answer here, if nobody answers.

Comment: The link you posted has all the information you need. I'll mark this question to be closed in the mean time. Please post if you have a more specific question when you do try to generate the documentation with md.

Comment: In Maven the default is apt oder xdoc format ...currently there is no maven-plugin to handle GitHub Markdown.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Quote from http://maven.apache.org/doxia/references/index.html

Add this to `pom.xml`

```
          <plugin>    
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.2</version>
              <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
                  <artifactId>doxia-module-markdown</artifactId>
                  <version>1.3</version>
                </dependency>
              </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Then start adding pages under `src/site/markdown/` with `.md` extension.
For every page add menu item like in sniplet below:

```
 <body>
    <!-- http://maven.apache.org/doxia/doxia-sitetools/doxia-decoration-model/decoration.html 
    <item collapse=.. ref=.. name=.. href="README" img=.. position=.. alt=.. border=.. width=.. height=.. target=.. title=.. >
    -->
    <menu name="User guide">
      <item href="README.html" name="README" />
    </menu>

    <menu ref="reports" inherit="bottom" />
  </body>
```

Than use `mvn site` to generate site.
Look at `target/site` to review results.

`mvn site:stage -DstagingDirectory=C:\TEMP\fullsite` to get multi-modular project site in one folder.

Read more about [maven-site-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/).

I recommend to use [maven-fluido-skin](http://maven.apache.org/skins/maven-fluido-skin/). It is newest style, based on Twitter Bootstrap
 Add this to site.xml

```
<project name="xxx">
  [...]
  <skin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.skins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-fluido-skin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
  </skin>
  [...]
</project>
```

See also
https://github.com/winterstein/Eclipse-Markdown-Editor-Plugin

Comment: This post needs to be added to the Doxia documentation since it's not clear to those of us who have not used Maven to manage documentation how this is done.  Thanks.

Comment: Open-source example https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/src/site

Comment: Thanks for this. I was looking for Markdown for generating site using Maven, and this works perfectly!

Comment: Ask question on stackoverflow.com :) using similar tags, and possibly referencing this question.

Comment: I added several futher informations to my project: issueManagement, ciManagement, organization, scm and description. If these are added - the doxia-Plugin will not get fired and markdown is not compiled. Just wantet to add this - perhaps somebody has the same error(?).

Answer (score 5):

Another standard way is to use the **Maven Site Plugin** as follows

- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/
- https://illegalexception.schlichtherle.de/maven/2013/06/17/how-to-use-markdown-syntax-with-the-maven-site-plugin/

With this approach, you can take advantage of the velocity template engine filtering. So it adds more power to your documentation.

Comment: This approach take advantages of the velocity template engine filtering that the site plugin does http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creating-content.html#Filtering Apparently, your markdown can reference to maven variables like ${project.name}